# How to perform/run background services in a custom Android OS like MIUI?

Tags: java, android, service, background-process

I am trying to implement a simple service demo in Android. When I start the service, it should run in the background even if I close the activity.
However on my Redmi phone (running MIUI OS) my service does not show as running when I close the activity.
It works with the stock OS like on a Moto phone.
Can you guys tell me how to do that?

Here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public  void start(View v)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(i);

    }
    public void stop(View v)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        stopService(i);
    }
}
```

Here is my Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: In miui you have to manage app auto-start (background service ) through the phpne settings. Have  look at [this](https://xiaomininja.com/2015/08/10/miui-tip-enable-autostart-to-never-miss-a-notification-again/)

Comment: thanks man it worked.I want to know how to instruct a user to enable this while installing the app.I mean how to know what device it is and accordingly provide necessary instruction to the user

Comment: @ShubhamGoel: You should post an answer with that link and a quote of the relevant information.